# Загружаю объект map из json файла, но найти его размер не получается, выводит undefined

Tags: javascript, json, map, discord-jda

Загружаю json файл и записываю в объект Map. Потом хочу узнать размер объекта(то есть сколько там таймеров), но консоль выводит undefined.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

вот код команда:

```
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
let timer = new Map();
timer = require('../jsons/timer.json');
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if (args[0] == 'amount') {
        let gld = message.member.guild.id;
        console.log(`На сервере ${timer[gld].length} таймеров.`);
    }
};
module.exports.help = {
    name: "timer"
};
```

вот json файл:

```
{
    "guild_id": {
        "1": {
            "time": 1000,
            "iteration": true,
            "author_nick": "nick",
            "author_id": "id"
        },
        "2": {
            "time": 10000,
            "iteration": true,
            "author_nick": "nick",
            "author_id": "id"
        }
    }
}
```

> на месте guild_id стоит настоящий айди гильдии в дискорде.

---

---

Изменение в коде:

```
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
let timer = new Map(
    Object.entries(
        require('../jsons/timer.json')
    )
);
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if (args[0] == 'amount') {
        let gld = String(message.member.guild.id);
        console.log(`На сервере ${timer["guild_id"].size} таймеров.`);
    }
};
module.exports.help = {
    name: "timer"
};
```

Comment: не надо полностью менять вопрос, иначе ответ становится неактуальным. Лучше _дополнять_ вопрос, либо задавать новый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это так не работает:

```
let timer = new Map();
timer = require('../jsons/timer.json');
```

Результат, который возвращает `require` просто **заменяет** значение `new Map()`, таким образом, в переменной будет простой объект, а не `Map`.

Кроме того, у `Map` нет свойства `length`, есть свойство [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size)

---

Чтобы на основе объекта сформировать `Map`, можно воспользоваться тем, что [конструктор `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) может принимать итерируемый объект.

Объект каждый элемент должен иметь вид: `[key, value]`

Для получения такого объекта можно воспользоваться методом [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
let timer = new Map(
    Object.entries(
        require('../jsons/timer.json')
    )
);
```

---

Для получения значения по ключу, в `Map` используется метод [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get)

Таким образом код должен получения такой

```
timer.get("guild_id")
```

---

Чтобы узнать количество свойств в объекте, нужно посмотреть количество ключей/значений либо просто в цикле посчитать.

метод [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) вернет массив ключей. Достаточно будет взять у него `length`

```
let timer = require('../jsons/timer.json');
...
console.log(`На сервере ${Object.keys(timer[gld]).length} таймеров.`);
```

Comment: тогда как сделать из объекта объект map?

Comment: @Youliam, обновил ответ

Comment: я заменил преобразование объекта, но консоль всё ещё выдаёт ошибку, но она уже другая: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined,
Также изменил код в вопросе

Comment: @Youliam, _Cannot read property 'size' of undefined_ - говорит, что объект у которого ты пытаешься вызвать `size` - undefined, это значит что у тебя в твоем Map нет ключа соответствующей гильдии

Comment: по json файлу ключ -
> соответствующей гильдии,
я написал словами как в исправленном коде, и ошибка всё ещё появляется

Comment: @Youliam, обновил ответ. У тебя у объектов в json нет свойства size - ты уверен что оно должно быть?

Comment: Я не знаю должно ли оно быть, но я пытаюсь найти как-то кол-во таймеров. Я думал что можно json файл перевести в объект Map, раз он на него похож, а затем узнать его длину. timer.get("guild_id").size - выдаёт undefined без ошибки.

Comment: @Youliam, ты переводишь не тот объект просто. Ты переводишь **весь** объект из json, а тебе нужно только для конкретного свойства.

Comment: @Youliam, собственно из-за плохо сформулированного вопроса и ты получил в ответ совсем не то, что тебе надо ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Не подскажешь ли какой объект и как его перевести для того чтобы узнать длину, я не силён в javascript. Мне кажется у этого json файла объект Map внутри которого ещё два объекта Map.
Или мне создать новый вопрос?